# TypeScript define object structure for later use

Tags: typescript, declare

Is it possible to define an object structure in TypeScript that can be used then as parameter type?

What I mean:
I have *(let's say)* 5 functions that return the same object structure like so:

```
foo(): { bar: string, baz: boolean, idk: number } { ... }
bar(): { bar: string, baz: boolean, idk: number } { ... }
...
```

the problem with this is that I have to define this structure at every function that returns an object like this.

So is it possible to do something like the following?

```
declare const OBJECT_STRUCTURE: { bar: string, baz: boolean, idk: number }

foo(): OBJECT_STRUCTURE { ... }
bar(): OBJECT_STRUCTURE { ... }
...
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface MyType {
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean;
    idk: number;
}

function foo(): MyType { 
    return {
        bar: "bar",
        baz: true,
        idk: 4
    };
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyType%20%7B%0A%09bar%3A%20string%3B%0A%09baz%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%09idk%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo()%3A%20MyType%20%7B%20%0A%09return%20%7B%0A%09%09bar%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%0A%09%09baz%3A%20true%2C%0A%09%09idk%3A%204%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D))

Or a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
type MyType = {
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean;
    idk: number;
}

function foo(): MyType { 
    return {
        bar: "bar",
        baz: true,
        idk: 4
    };
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyType%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09bar%3A%20string%3B%0A%09baz%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%09idk%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo()%3A%20MyType%20%7B%20%0A%09return%20%7B%0A%09%09bar%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%0A%09%09baz%3A%20true%2C%0A%09%09idk%3A%204%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D))

Comment: in case anyone is wondering what's for what: Type Aliases good for for creating simple, reusable types, Interfaces for defining the structure of objects and classes and being able to extend them.

Answer (score 4):

> So is it possible to do something like the following

A simple `type` declaration:

```
type OBJECT_STRUCTURE = { bar: string, baz: boolean, idk: number }
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html

Answer (score 2):

A really native solution to TS is - declare interface

```
export interface IMyObject { 
    bar: string;
    baz: boolean; 
    idk: number;
}
```

And that could be easily reused everywhere, without re-declaring it

```
foo(): IMyObject { ... }
bar(): IMyObject  { ... }
```

or

```
other(obj: IMyObject) { ... }
```